# Custom view controller instead of table view controller in Side menu

Tags: ios, swift, side-menu

I am using sidemenu library to get the menu from the left side.But by default it uses tableview controller to display the menu items. I want to change this to uiviewcontroller. How do I do it?

Library link: https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu

Comment: Just replace it by your custom view controller

Comment: At first it was not working. Now it started to work. I didn't add it as rootview controller that was the problem..